# I'm having trouble accessing session information in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backend

If there is a successful login at my login endpoint, I define the session to mongodb _uid and I can get my session with req.session.userID from any get request, but I cannot receive it in post requests, it returns undefined, the relevant code parts are below

--- app.js

```
// Express.js ve Mongoose kütüphanelerini içe aktar
const express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongoStore = require("connect-mongo");
const session = require("express-session");

// Sayfa, kurs, kategori ve kullanıcı rotalarını içe aktar
const pageRoute = require("./routes/pageRoute"); // Modül yolunu gerçek modül yolunuzla değiştirin
const courseRoute = require("./routes/courseRoute");
const categoryRoute = require("./routes/categoryRoute");
const userRoute = require("./routes/userRoute");

// Express uygulamasını oluştur
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors());

// MongoDB veritabanına bağlantı
const startServer = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1/educationDB");
    console.log("Veritabanına bağlanıldı");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Veritabanına bağlanılamadı:", err);
  }
};

startServer();

// Şablon Motoru olarak EJS'yi kullan
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// global değişkenler
global.userStatus = null;

// Middleware'lar
// - 'public' klasörünü statik dosyalar için kullan
app.use(express.static("public"));
// - URL'yi analiz etmek ve req.body içine form verilerini eklemek için 'urlencoded' middleware'i kullan
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// - JSON verileri için 'json' middleware'i kullan
app.use(express.json());

// 'session' middleware'ini kullan
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "my_keyboard_cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: mongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: "mongodb://127.0.0.1/educationDB" }),
  })
);

// '*' route'una özel bir middleware ekleyerek oturum bilgisini res.locals'a atayın
app.use("*", (req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.userStatus = req.session.userID;
  next();
});

// Rotalar
// - '/' rotası için pageRoute middleware'ini kullan
app.use("/", pageRoute);
// - '/courses' rotası için courseRoute middleware'ini kullan
app.use("/courses", courseRoute);
// - '/categories' rotası için categoryRoute middleware'ini kullan
app.use("/categories", categoryRoute);
// - '/users' rotası için userRoute middleware'ini kullan
app.use("/users", userRoute);

// Sunucuyu dinle
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Uygulama http://localhost:${port} adresinde dinleniyor`);
});
```

--- authController.js

```
exports.createUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("aşağıda session bilgisi olması lazım");
    console.log(req.session.userID);
    // Kullanıcı modeli üzerinden yeni bir kullanıcı oluştur
    const findUser = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    findUser &&
      res.status(400).render("register", {
        page_name: "register",
        message:
          "Bu email adresi ile bir kullanıcı zaten mevcut. Lütfen farklı bir email adresi ile kayıt olunuz.",
      });
    const user = await User.create(req.body);

    // Başarılı bir şekilde kullanıcı oluşturulduğunda 201 status koduyla birlikte JSON yanıtı gönder
    res.status(201).redirect("/login");
  } catch (error) {
    // Kullanıcı oluşturma işlemi başarısız olduğunda 400 status koduyla birlikte hata mesajı gönder
    res.status(400);
    console.log(error);
  }
};

exports.loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // HTTP isteğinden gelen e-posta ve şifre bilgilerini çıkar
    const { email, password } = req.query;

    // Veritabanında kullanıcıyı e-posta adresine göre ara
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (user) {
      // Kullanıcı bulunduysa, şifreleri karşılaştır
      const same = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (same) {
        // Şifreler eşleşiyorsa, başarılı giriş mesajını döndür
        req.session.userID = user._id;
        if (req.session.userID) {
          return res.status(200).redirect("/users/dashboard");
        }
      }
    }
    // Kullanıcı bulunamadı veya şifre eşleşmediyse hata mesajını döndür
    res.status(401).render("login", {
      page_name: "login",
      message: "Incorrect email or password",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // Hata durumunda, hata mesajını içeren bir JSON yanıtı döndür
    res.status(400);
    console.log("Hata:", error);
  }
};
```

I tried permissions with cors, I tried session settings. I tried adding the global variable middleware

Comment: How do you send the post request?

Comment: Since I haven't set up the pages yet, I'm sending them via postman.

Comment: Do you send the cookies with the post request?

Comment: I guess yes, where do we check? I'm new at this.

Comment: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/cookies/

Comment: Yes, I send it with cookie